# How can i make this javascript code countdown print 0-0-0-0 if the date is expired?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im not so good in JavaScript and i need this countdown code to print 0 in the 4 circles if the date is expired instead of printing the exact expired date ..

The countdown is on Codepen Made by the user Noel Peña (thanks to him of course for this amazing countdown): http://codepen.io/ewganoel/pen/AIGcE

And here is the JavaScript Code :

```
var ringer = {
countdown_to: "10/10/2014",
rings: {
'DAYS': {
s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
max: 365
},
'HOURS': {
s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
max: 24
},
'MINUTES': {
s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
max: 60
},
'SECONDS': {
s: 1000,
max: 60
},
'MICROSEC': {
s: 10,
max: 100
}
},
r_count: 5,
r_spacing: 10, // px
r_size: 100, // px
r_thickness: 5, // px
update_interval: 11, // ms


init: function(){

$r = ringer;
$r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas');

$r.size = {
w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing*($r.r_count-1)),
h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness)
};



$r.cvs.setAttribute('width',$r.size.w);
$r.cvs.setAttribute('height',$r.size.h);
$r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
$(".countdownwrap").append($r.cvs);
$r.cvs = $($r.cvs);
$r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
$r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
$r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
$r.cvs.css({ width: $r.size.w+"px", height: $r.size.h+"px" });
$r.go();
},
ctx: null,
go: function(){
var idx=0;

$r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


for(var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++,r_key,$r.rings[r_key]);

setTimeout($r.go,$r.update_interval);
},
unit: function(idx,label,ring) {
var x,y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
value = parseFloat($r.time/ring_secs);
$r.time-=Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
value = Math.abs(value);

x = ($r.r_size*.5 + $r.r_thickness*.5);
x +=+(idx*($r.r_size+$r.r_spacing+$r.r_thickness));
y = $r.r_size*.5;
y += $r.r_thickness*.5;


// calculate arc end angle
var degrees = 360-(value / ring.max) * 360.0;
var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

$r.ctx.save();

$r.ctx.translate(x,y);
$r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size,$r.actual_size);

// first circle
$r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)";
$r.ctx.beginPath();
$r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,2 * Math.PI, 2);
$r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
$r.ctx.stroke();

// second circle
$r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(253, 128, 1, 0.9)";
$r.ctx.beginPath();
$r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,endAngle, 1);
$r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
$r.ctx.stroke();

// label
$r.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

$r.ctx.font = '12px Helvetica';
$r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);
$r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);

$r.ctx.font = 'bold 40px Helvetica';
$r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 10);

$r.ctx.restore();
}
}

ringer.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `countdown_to` time to a future date.

and update the code

```
if(((new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time)<0)
     $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;
else $r.time = 0;
```

check if difference of current `new Date().getTime()` to `countdown_to_time` is greater than zero then set it to zero.

Here is a example,

```js
var ringer = {
  countdown_to: "1/10/2017",
  rings: {
    'DAYS': {
      s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
      max: 365
    },
    'HOURS': {
      s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
      max: 24
    },
    'MINUTES': {
      s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
      max: 60
    },
    'SECONDS': {
      s: 1000,
      max: 60
    },
    'MICROSEC': {
      s: 10,
      max: 100
    }
  },
  r_count: 5,
  r_spacing: 10, // px
  r_size: 100, // px
  r_thickness: 5, // px
  update_interval: 11, // ms


  init: function() {

    $r = ringer;
    $r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas');

    $r.size = {
      w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing * ($r.r_count - 1)),
      h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness)
    };



    $r.cvs.setAttribute('width', $r.size.w);
    $r.cvs.setAttribute('height', $r.size.h);
    $r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
    $(".countdownwrap").append($r.cvs);
    $r.cvs = $($r.cvs);
    $r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    $r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
    $r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
    $r.cvs.css({
      width: $r.size.w + "px",
      height: $r.size.h + "px"
    });
    $r.go();
  },
  ctx: null,
  go: function() {
    var idx = 0;

    if (((new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time) < 0)
      $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;
    else $r.time = 0;

    for (var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++, r_key, $r.rings[r_key]);


    setTimeout($r.go, $r.update_interval);
  },
  unit: function(idx, label, ring) {
    var x, y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
    value = parseFloat($r.time / ring_secs);
    $r.time -= Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
    value = Math.abs(value);

    x = ($r.r_size * .5 + $r.r_thickness * .5);
    x += +(idx * ($r.r_size + $r.r_spacing + $r.r_thickness));
    y = $r.r_size * .5;
    y += $r.r_thickness * .5;


    // calculate arc end angle
    var degrees = 360 - (value / ring.max) * 360.0;
    var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    $r.ctx.save();

    $r.ctx.translate(x, y);
    $r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size * -0.5, $r.actual_size * -0.5, $r.actual_size, $r.actual_size);

    // first circle
    $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)";
    $r.ctx.beginPath();
    $r.ctx.arc(0, 0, $r.r_size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 2);
    $r.ctx.lineWidth = $r.r_thickness;
    $r.ctx.stroke();

    // second circle
    $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(253, 128, 1, 0.9)";
    $r.ctx.beginPath();
    $r.ctx.arc(0, 0, $r.r_size / 2, 0, endAngle, 1);
    $r.ctx.lineWidth = $r.r_thickness;
    $r.ctx.stroke();

    // label
    $r.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

    $r.ctx.font = '12px Helvetica';
    $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);
    $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);

    $r.ctx.font = 'bold 40px Helvetica';
    $r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 10);

    $r.ctx.restore();
  }
}

ringer.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdownwrap"></div>
```

Comment: oh tanks a lot .. saved my life

Comment: Welcome, an up-vote would have been better though :)

Comment: that's will be the least i can do but unfortunately : *Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score* .. i'm so sorry and i really appreciated it thanks a lot .. very much .. you saved my day .. thanks a gain (: